# Apply matrix to sphere/Object3D

Tags: java, opengl-es, three.js, rajawali

I have a 360° panorama picture (texture) that I map around a sphere and I place my camera inside the sphere to have a spherical projection. Now the texture is projected on the outside of the sphere.
I want to 'turn the texture inside-out' and i read it could be done by applying a matrix.

I'd like to apply a matrix to a sphere (Object3D) in Rajawali/OpenGL.

This can be done in ThreeJS like this:

```
var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 100, 40);
sphere.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(-1, 1, 1));
```

three.js documentation for applyMatrix:

> this updates the position, rotation and scale with the matrix.

and I'd like to do this in Rajawali:

```
mSphere = new Sphere(100, 100, 40);
//Apply the matrix here
```

Documentation for Matrix/Object3D can be found here
[Matrix4](https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali/blob/master/src/rajawali/math/Matrix4.java)
[Object3D](https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali/blob/master/src/rajawali/Object3D.java)

Or is there any other way it could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed!

```
mSphere = new Sphere(100, 100, 40);
mSphere.setScaleX(-1);
mSphere.setScaleY(1);
mSphere.setScaleZ(1);
```

Comment: Bear in mind that you may need to adjust the camera's field of view. I've set it to 105°, which appears to be a good angle for Cardboard.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that really a job for *material.side*?

Quote from three.js doc for Material:

> .side
>
> Defines which of the face sides will be rendered - front, back or both.
> Default is THREE.FrontSide. Other options are THREE.BackSide and THREE.DoubleSide.

So looking at a sphere surface from the inside should be using *THREE.BackSide*.